# Managing NullPointer Exception in SpringBoot Web-flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, spring-webflux

My code calls for Mono element from Flux base of elements (already created). Includes @Repository class with "getJobById" and @Component class "Handler" to process request like getAll, getJobById, post, put, delete. If I input wrong id - can't handle exception and receive NullPointerException error. 
I want to catch the exception instead.

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null at com.javasampleapproach.webflux.repo.impl.JobClientRepositoryImpl.getJobById(JobClientRepositoryImpl.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.javasampleapproach.webflux.functional.handler.JobClientHandler.getJobById(JobClientHandler.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
```

Already tried this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ClientExceptionController  {
@ExceptionHandler(value = ClientNotfoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> exception(ClientNotfoundException exception) {return new ResponseEntity<>("Id not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);}

+

public class ClientNotfoundException extends NullPointerException{
    public ClientNotfoundException() {}
    public ClientNotfoundException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

and in Handler and Repository classes:

if(jobClientRepository.getJobById(jobId).equals(null)) throw new ClientNotfoundException();
```

Also I tried like:

```
 Mono<JobClient> jobMono = jobClientRepository.getJobById(jobId)
.onErrorResume(e->Mono.empty());
 @Component
    public Mono<ServerResponse> getJobById(ServerRequest request) {
            long jobId = Long.valueOf(request.pathVariable("id"));
            Mono<ServerResponse> notFound = ServerResponse.notFound().build();
```

And I tried this:

```
  if(jobClientRepository.getJobById(jobId).equals(null)) throw new ClientNotfoundException();
```

Error appears here:

```
Mono<JobClient> jobMono = jobClientRepository.getJobById(jobId).onErrorResume(e->Mono.empty());
return jobMono.flatMap(job -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(fromObject(job))).switchIfEmpty(notFound).onErrorResume(ClientNotfoundException.class, e -> notFound);

@Repository 
@Override
public Mono<JobClient> getJobById(Long id)  {if(jobStores.get(id).equals(null)) throw new ClientNotfoundException();
return Mono.just(jobStores.get(id)).onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new ClientNotfoundException("Correct ID is required"+e)));
```

Comment: Did you try handling the error in your service class instead of overriding the method in repository?

Comment: You mean if I added like .doOnError, or like described here https://blog.knoldus.com/spring-webflux-error-handling-in-reactive-streams/ - I did.

Comment: You sure this is how null checks done in java `if(jobStores.get(id).equals(null))`?

Comment: Sagarr - not sure) Im beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate regular programming from reactive programming. Try this.

```
@Repository 
@Override
public Mono<JobClient> getJobById(Long id)  {
    return Optional.ofNullable(jobStore.get(id))
            .map(Mono::just)
            .orElseGet(Mono::empty);
}

//Then call it
getJobById(1L).map(jobClient -> ServerResponse.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .syncBody(jobClient)
        ).switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(ClientNotfoundException::new));
```

Havnt run the code wrote it on mobile.

Comment: Dear Thomas, here in the last line I got the error in class with lambda ".switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(ClientNotfoundException::new));" "Throwable is not a functional interface."

Comment: Error when you run it or during compile time. Because during compile time it works on my end.

Comment: while I wrote a code - class ClientNotfoundException underlined with red

Comment: to be more precise - error while compiling "Error:(60, 29) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Throwable is not a functional interface" and its about above mentioned class.

Comment: ClientNotfoundException.class is your class?

Comment: Almost empty class public class ClientNotfoundException extends NullPointerException{
    public ClientNotfoundException() {}
    public ClientNotfoundException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}

Comment: i just checked in my IDEA, and it compiles, so you will have to post your code because clearly you must have implemented it wrong then.

Comment: Thomas is it allowed/usual here to do links on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Repository 
@Override
public Mono<JobClient> getJobById(Long id)  {
    if(jobStores.get(id) == null) throw new ClientNotfoundException();
    return Mono.just(jobStores.get(id)).onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new ClientNotfoundException("Correct ID is required"+e)));
}
```

In java you avoid `NullPointerException` by first checking whether given object is null or not and then proceed with calling its method like

```
if (obj != null) {
    obj.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Dear Sagarr still error but now different one: "com.javasampleapproach.webflux.Exception.ClientNotfoundException: null" and the "jobStores.get(id) == null" I tried first, sorry didn't get initially different error.